# Readable text when copy-pasted from PDF becomes completely unreadable

Tags: pdf, copy-paste, character-encoding

What is this that when I select a completely readable, Latin (no language-specific characters, actually a company name and street address) text in PDF document and then copy and paste it to any destination (namely: Word, Notepad, Notepad++, browser, Gmail) I get such thing:

```
'ĂŵĂŶ͘ƉůdŽŵĂƐnjdƌĞũĚĞƌŽǁƐŬŝ
Ƶů͘'ƌĂŶŝĐnjŶĂςϭĂͬϭϬ
κϬͲϬϭΘ<ĂƚŽǁŝĐĞ
E/W͗ερκϮϭεςκϯρ
```

The above is copy-pasted to browser (Chrome) / Gmails and to Word. When I copy the same text from PDF and paste it to Notepad++ instead, I get something like this (similar, but not the same):

[image]

I am getting the same results no matter if I copy text from Gmail's / Chrome's PDF preview (original document is attached to an e-mail) or if I save the file and open it up in Foxit Reader.

Is this a problem with character encoding or some kind of weird encryption?

Is there any workaround for getting (copy-pasting) actual text from source PDF? Or do I have manualy typing as the only option left?

Comment: Use OCR for to convert your PDF to readable text. I.e. print to 300+ dpi graphic (for example, TIFF) and recognize it.

Comment: This comment is all wrong. If I am saying that I can copy-paste a text from my PDF then this clearly mean that I already have it as readable text. No OCR needed.

Comment: *I am saying that I can copy-paste a text from my PDF* You have tried... are you happy with the result? My method will give clear, readable and editable text, not a meaningless set of symbols.